# Overlapping/overlaying multiple inline images

Tags: html, css, sass, z-index, overlap

I have a list of images I'm trying to overlap so that they look similar to this:

[image: overlapped people]

My code:

```css
.avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
    <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/70" width="25" height="25"/>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" width="25" height="25"/>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/20" width="25" height="25"/>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" width="25" height="25"/>
    </span>
    <!-- Variable amount more avatars -->
</div>
<p>4 People</p>
```

But obviously, I need an incrementing `left` value, and a decrementing `z-index` for the number of avatar imgs. Sure, I could do this with the `@for` directive, but the thing is, there's a variable amount of avatar imgs. I was looking at the `length()` function, but it doesn't work the way I was going to use it.

Another idea, is to have a set width div, and fit the images inside that, but that comes with its own issues (what if there are 5 images, or 20, how do control the width). I could also combine the images how I want them, elsewhere and not use any CSS.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use flex and reverse order then no need z-index:

```css
.avatars {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

.avatar:not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <span class="avatar">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/70">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/80">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/90">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is another idea with scale:

```css
.avatars {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

.avatar:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <span class="avatar">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/70">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/80">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/90">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    </span>
</div>
```

Another idea using mask in case you want to keep the order of your images. This will also give you transparency between the images:

```css
.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

.avatar:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -60px;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle 55px at 5px 50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%);
          mask:radial-gradient(circle 55px at 5px 50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%);
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  background:pink
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <span class="avatar">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/70">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/80">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/90">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    </span>
</div>
```

Another idea using a 3D tranformation trick (without transparency)

```css
.avatars {
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* here */
}

.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

.avatar:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -60px;
  transform:rotateY(-1deg); /* and here */
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <span class="avatar">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/70">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/80">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/90">
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

I like [Temani's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916502/4665) better, but if you can't use flex because you have to support IE 9 or earlier, I'll leave this here.

Note that the text direction is now right to left, so you'll need to reverse the order of your avatars.

```css
.avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.avatars {
  direction: rtl;  /* This is to get the stack with left on top */
  text-align: left;  /* Now need to explitly align left */
  padding-left: 25px;  /* Same value as the negative margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" width="50" height="50"/>
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100" width="50" height="50"/>
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" width="50" height="50"/>
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/150/150" width="50" height="50"/>
    </span>
  <span class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" width="50" height="50"/>
    </span>
  <!-- Variable amount more avatars -->
</div>
```

Comment: Im so happy that your answer showed me this great source of placeholder-content. Should be in every developers toolbox

Answer (score 0):

Tried the reverse flex idea which worked but messed up my lists as I need to preserve order and having them reversed beforehand messes up another list I have where I'd need to reverse again ‍

What I'm doing now is
`flex -space-x-2` on the container

And in the loop, with index, have each item get a z-index of the total length of the list minus the current index, which works like a charm for me

```
z-index: array.length - index
```

If you're not using tailwind here's what's happening

```css
.-space-x-2 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
}
```

I stripped some tailwind magic, it's basically selecting each (non hidden) child after the first (so the first child isn't selected) using the [child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and [General sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

But I think I'll try the mask approach [Temani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916502/3484824) mentioned as well at some point