# Stacking elements in reverse order using css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-grid

I have the following concentric circles structure created with HTML5 + CSS3 using css-grid. I want to change the order of stacking to be reversed.

By default, each elements are stacked from left to right, right element coming above left one.

I have tried different ways to reverse the order and nothing is working.

Any suggestions?

```css
.group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 18%);
  width: 200px;
}

.circle {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
    <div class="circle">5</div>
    <div class="circle">6</div>
    <div class="circle">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916502/8620333 ?

Comment: I want to implement using css grid. both questions are related to css flexboxes

Comment: any reason to use CSS grid? as a side note the question isn't related to flexbox, there is 3 different ways and only one use flexbox

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to change order when switching between `rtl` and `ltr`. The entire page is decided to use css-grid, so I have to use the css grid.

Answer (score 2):

**With CSS Grid**:

There is a CSS property that Grid Layout adheres to called direction.  `direction: rtl` will give you what you need with a single additional class:

```
.reverse-order{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

JSFiddle for your question: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/92f0143c/1/)

**Without CSS Grid**:

You can do it via adding the following CSS classes, use the appropriate class as needed:

```
.normal-order {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.reverse-order > div {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Comment: Your Answer look promising. I already checked the `rtl` `ltr` values for `direction` property.

The problem here is - I don't want the order of items reversed. I only want to change the stacking.

When we add the direction property the item `1` moved to the end, instead of staying at front.