# creating overlapping user icons

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a a component that overlaps over the user icons just as shown in the photo. I've seen this being used on google. If I have a list of user icons, how do I overlap them over each other?

I want something like this [image].

```
<template>
    <div >
    <ul>
      <li v-for="user in userList" :key="user.key">
        <user-icon-component :name="user.name" :image="user.picture"></user-icon-component>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "UserList",
  props: {
    userList: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48916431/8620333

Answer (score 2):

The icon component is just an `<img>` tag with a `user` prop:

```js
Vue.component('user-icon-component', {
  props: ['user'],
  template: `
  <img :src="user.picture" width="32" height="32" />
  `
})
```

Give the `<li>s` `position: absolute` and the `<ul>` `position: relative` to pull them out of the normal document flow.  Set the `left` position on each `<li>` as a calculation from the `index` of the loop:

```html
<ul class="icon-container">
  <li v-for="(user, key, i) in userList" :key="user.key"
      class="icon" :style="{ left: `${i * 20}px` }">
    <user-icon-component :user="user"></user-icon-component>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
Vue.component('user-icon-component', {
    props: ['user'],
  template: `
  <img :src="user.picture" width="32" height="32" />
  `
})

/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        userList: {
        'Bob': { name: 'Bob', key: 1, picture: 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3084/3084430.svg' },
        'Mary': { name: 'Mary', key: 2, picture: 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3084/3084431.svg' },
        'Paul': { name: 'Paul', key: 3, picture: 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3084/3084452.svg' },
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.icon-container {
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="icon-container">
    <li v-for="(user, key, i) in userList" :key="user.key"
        class="icon" :style="{ left: `${i * 20}px` }">
      <user-icon-component :user="user"></user-icon-component>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did exactly as you did but it isn't even showing the circle icons. the circle component accepts `:name` and ':picture`. the way I did, is it correct to send them like that?

Comment: You could pass the properties individually like that, but I think it makes more sense to pass the whole `user` object.  It works either way.  Maybe try to copy and paste the code from the answer in case something is different than you realize

Comment: It says that `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "userList".  Expected Object, got Array ` @Dan Now the circles show but the pictures don't show..

Comment: I did exactly what you did. Not sure why it says that it got an array

Comment: I'm using storybooks. and it all shows [object Object] in the props area

Comment: the date will come from the server in json array of pictures of name and picture format. so I can't change the format of the props. Is it possible to get the name and picture out of that array of object?

Comment: That does not change whether you can pass the `user`.  My first answer was for an array of objects and I updated it because you said it's an object of objects.  I think you'll need to post your code to https://www.codesandbox.io with an example of all of your data because i've already shown both ways

Answer (score 2):

I liked the idea in your question and took it as a challenge for myself and here is the result:

[vue overlapping avatars component](https://codepen.io/Hamid-Niakan/pen/mdrmBOM)

basically the approach I took was to use the component's `props` as style in style binding. there are some `scoped style` as well but I think they can be set in the style binding as well if needs be (probably the code could be cleaner).

user prop is an array of objects that contains this property: `img: 'imageURL'` and using a `v-for` on a `div` element with:

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${user.img})`}"
```

we can set the images.

as for the overlapping part, `div`s have `position: relative` and using the `index` of `v-for`, the style binding becomes like this:

```
:style="{backgroundImage: `url(${user.img})`, left: `-${i*15}px`}"
```

which shifts every element to the left by 15px except for the first one.

here is the image of the final result:

[image]

Thanks for your question, it was fun :)