# How to overflow the images on the previous ones?

Tags: html, css, image, drupal, transform

I have several images and I want to make a presentation like on Facebook, by unwinding the images on the previous ones :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THdGM.png)

Here are my images, they are with a View Drupal 9 block :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc7K0.png)

I created the following CSS :

```
.block-views-blockgroup-subscribers-block-1 .view-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}

.block-views-blockgroup-subscribers-block-1 .views-field-user-picture img {
    border: 2px solid #f7f9fa;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
}
```

But it doesn't work because the images are not displayed on top of the previous image.

How to overflow the images on the previous ones ?

Comment: You could use a negative `margin-left` value instead of `transform`. For instance: `margin-left: -8px`.

Comment: @c0m1t If I make a negative margin, all the images are offset by 8 px. I want them to overlap by -8px on the previous image and that the first image is not shifted.

Comment: Your issue is that the first image is shifted due to the negative margin? If so set 0 as its margin. You can use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) CSS pseudo-class to select the first child, an `img` element in this case. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-moore-ozf7ul?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916431/overlapping-overlaying-multiple-inline-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the best method which I used. Hope You can use this method.**

```css
.default-avatar {
  background-color: #47d501;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.default-avatar,
.member-overlap-item {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.member-overlap-item {
  margin-right: -10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.group {
  min-height: 40px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

.grid-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}

.group-class {
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-11 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
         <a class="route d-flex">
              <div title="Baby Yoda" class="rounded-circle default-avatar member-overlap-item" style="background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/layering-profile-images/master/images/baby-yoda.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
              </div>
              <div title="R2D2" class="rounded-circle default-avatar member-overlap-item" style="background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/layering-profile-images/master/images/r2d2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
              </div>
              <div title="Jabba the Hut" class="rounded-circle default-avatar member-overlap-item" style="background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/layering-profile-images/master/images/jabba-the-hut.png) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
              </div>
              <div title="Chewbacca" class="rounded-circle default-avatar member-overlap-item" style="background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/layering-profile-images/master/images/chewy.png) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
              </div>
              <div title="C-3PO" class="rounded-circle default-avatar member-overlap-item" style="background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/layering-profile-images/master/images/c-3po.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
              </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works, how to put the first image over the next and so on?

Comment: Please check the class name and properties,

.member-overlap-item {
  margin-right: -10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

Comment: forget about bootstrap. paste this css class to your stylesheet along with previous styles >>
.route{
display: flex;
}
.rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 50%!important;
}

Comment: In your example, the overlay of images should be reversed with the first on top of the others...

Comment: You can Use  flex-direction: row-reverse >>>
Ex: .route{ display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; }

Comment: Yes, but it reverses the images and I want to keep the order

Comment: Ordering your items using this >>>
 .route :nth-child(1) { order: 5; }
        .route :nth-child(2) { order: 4; }
        .route :nth-child(3) { order: 3; }
        .route :nth-child(4) { order: 2; }
        .route :nth-child(5) { order: 1; }

reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to say parent div to be flex, **and reverse it**. Reverse gives you the ability to avoid first image shift.
Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-paper-9xmrr3?file=/src/styles.css)

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.image-container img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```